# How to add editor css rules to Wordpress Gutenberg block popover itself?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Here are some Gutenberg blocks I am writing in Wordpress ediotr.

[image]

What i am trying to do is that chaning the position of the popover of Gutenberg Editor block slightly.

[image]

Since it appears in front of very previous block, I cannot select the previous paragragh block because of it.

I found out a proper rule to solve the problem for me in the developer mode like below

[image]

So I have added a css rule in the editor-style.css file:

```
 .components-popover__content {
    position: relative !important;
    top: -4rem !important;
    left: 4.3rem !important;
 }
```

Of-course, I have added the editor style in function.php of my child theme.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'kyle_gutenberg_editor_css' );
function kyle_gutenberg_editor_css(){
    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' ); 
    add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css'); 
}
```

It has certainly added on the page with `<style>` tag:

[image]

However, Wordpress also adds a prefix `.editor-styles-wrapper` in frond of css selectors of the rules that I write. That's why I think it does not apply to the popover.

[image]

Unlike many solutions for custom Gutenberg blocks, I cannot find out the way to add css rules to the popover itself. How can I achive this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found out.

I previously used `after_setup_them` hook to add an editor style.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'kyle_gutenberg_editor_css' );
function kyle_gutenberg_editor_css(){
  add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' ); // if you don't add this line, your stylesheet won't be added
  add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css'); // tries to include style-editor.css directly from your theme folder
}
```

But we'd better use another hook when it comes to Gutenberg Editor.
`enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook was introduced in Wordpress 5.0.

Now, I wrote like this:

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'kyle_gutenberg_editor_css', 9999 );
function kyle_gutenberg_editor_css() {
   $css_file_modified_time = filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/editor-style.css');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'kyle-editor-styles', get_theme_file_uri( '/editor-style.css' ).'?time='.$css_file_modified_time, false, '' , 'all' );
}
```

now in my `editor-style.css`, a css rule with `.editor-styles-wrapper` applies to the body and any rule without `.editor-styles-wrapper` applies to the popover itself and other elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `add_editor_style()` is not what you think it is.
Here an example of mine that I use to load a CSS & JS file in the backend editor:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' ], 100 );


/**
 * Load the CSS & Javascript files for the admin
 */
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
        $theme             = wp_get_theme();

        $file_with_path_js = get_template_directory() . '/includes/my_file.js';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-editor-scripts', $file_with_path_js, '', $theme->Version, true );

        $file_with_path_css = get_template_directory() . '/includes/my_file.css';
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-editor-styles', $file_with_path_css, '', $theme->Version, 'all' );
}
```